# Checking arguments

Tags: javascript, arguments

What is the difference between these two ways of checking the arguments?

```
function foo(a, b) {
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
}
```

Using:

```
if (arguments.length === 1) {}
```

or

```
if (this.b !== undefined) {}
```

Comment: for what reason do you want to check it... I think there is no need to check for arguments when you know what will come into the function... if you have an unknown number of arguments passed to a function it is better to check against arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check mandatory arguments, I will use `arguments.length` as first step. If you want to check optional arguments, usually the pattern is:

```
function foo(a,b){
    this.a = a || "foo";
    // etc
}
```

Notice that this works only if the parameters can't be "falsy" values (so, empty string, zero, null, undefined, false, NaN). For example, if you pass an empty string as `a` parameter, you will have foo. If you want to consider only `undefined` as value for considering a parameter optional then you have to do something like:

```
function foo(a){
    this.a = a === undefined ? "foo" : a;
    // etc
}
```

If you want to consider both null and undefined and optional parameter, you can have:

```
function foo(a){
    this.a = a == undefined ? "foo" : a;
    // etc
}
```

Of course, you can also use the operator `typeof`. For instance you want that `a` can be only a string:

```
function foo(a) {
    this.a = typeof a === "string" ? a : "";
    // etc
}
```

You can also force `a` to be always a string, in the worst scenario will be the string version of the non-string value given (undefined as well):

```
function foo(a) {
    this.a = String(a);
    // etc
}
```

More complex cases have some utility functions that makes all this check for you, where you said the arguments required, the optional, the default value, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check in what terms? Can the function proceed with a default value/bahavior, or should it stop if something was missed?

Commonly you an default the behavior, but that depends on the purpose/use of the function:

```
function foo(a,b){
  a = a || {};
  b = b || 5;
  // continue
}
```

If you're looking for something absent, you can check `undefined` and halt:

```
function foo(a){
  if (a === undefined){
    return false;
  }
}
```

In short, it's entirely up to you and how you want a function to proceed given an absent or incorrectly assigned variable. Another for instance:

```
function bar(b){
  if (typeof b !== 'function'){
    b = function(){};
  }
  // continue on...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`b!==undefined` is most likely what you want

The first one will fail if you do foo() or f(1,2,3)